PrimeNg Tooltip disappearing on mobile and tablet when touch released even with life set or hidedelay set
I'm configuring a tooltip for a custom button and assigning a method to a (touchstart) event, because hover event for primeng tooltip is not working in tablet or mobiles.
This is the code for the method:
onTouch() {
   this.tooltip.hideDelay = 5000;
   this.tooltip.show();
}

The problem is that the delay is not working, when I release the touch the tooltip disappear. I need the tooltip to remain after touch is released for 5 seconds.
How should I do it? Tried timeout and left properties but not working.

modify your template to handle both touchstart and touchend events:
<button pTooltip="Your tooltip text" 
        #tt="pTooltip"
        (touchstart)="onTouchStart($event)"
        (touchend)="onTouchEnd()">
    Button Text
</button>

Then in your component, implement the logic to manage the tooltip visibility:
export class YourComponent {
  @ViewChild('tt') tooltip: any;
  private tooltipTimer: any;

  onTouchStart(event: TouchEvent) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default touch behavior
    this.tooltip.show();
  }

  onTouchEnd() {
    // Clear any existing timer
    if (this.tooltipTimer) {
      clearTimeout(this.tooltipTimer);
    }
    
    // Set new timer to hide tooltip after 5 seconds
    this.tooltipTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.tooltip.hide();
    }, 5000);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // Clean up timer when component is destroyed
    if (this.tooltipTimer) {
      clearTimeout(this.tooltipTimer);
    }
  }
}


Use both touchstart and touchend events to better control the tooltip behavior
Prevents the default touch behavior which might interfere with the tooltip

